# How to fadeIn an already visible object in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, zooming, fadein, fade, fadeout

I'm trying to make a photo gallery with jQuery, so when I click a thumbnail, it becomes a "zoombox", by fading in. Then I navigate with left & right arrows, with the function loadContentFrom(domObject) which looks like this:

```
function loadContentFrom(domObject)
{
    // metaspan is gonna be the content of #zoombox :
    var metaspan = domObject.children('.metaspan');

    // set the html by fading in :
    $("#zoombox").html(metaspan.html()).fadeIn(400);
    add_left_right_arrows_to_zoombox();

    // also set the background to be clickable for exit.
    $("#exitdiv").fadeIn(400); 
}
```

It works fine, when I click on a domObject it fades in. But when I click left - right arrows, it calls `loadContentFrom(selectedDomObject.next('.domobject'));` but since the zoombox is already faded in, it changes the content immediately.

So how can I set it to first fade out the current content, then fade in the new content?

Thanks !

Comment: use .hide().fadeIn(400)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this..

```
function loadContentFrom(domObject)
{
    // metaspan is gonna be the content of #zoombox :
    var metaspan = domObject.children('.metaspan');

    // set the html by fading in :
    $("#zoombox").html(metaspan.html()).fadeIn(400);
    add_left_right_arrows_to_zoombox();

    // also set the background to be clickable for exit.
    $("#exitdiv").hide().fadeIn(400); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers !

Comment: But this hides the zoombox, Whereas I want to hide the content of it. How can I modify hide() to do that ?

Comment: Do like this $("#exitdiv").not("#zoombox").hide().fadeIn(400);

Comment: I think I got it. I'm selecting the content of zoombox manually, and calling hide() on them. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can also use .effect() for nice effects in jQuery. Also visit http://www.easings.net for good effects.

Answer (score 0):

`FadeIn` will not work on `visible objects`, but you can use [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) before [fadein()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein)

like,

Like this..

```
function loadContentFrom(domObject)
{
    // metaspan is gonna be the content of #zoombox :
    var metaspan = domObject.children('.metaspan');

    // set the html by fading in :
    $("#zoombox").html(metaspan.html()).hide().fadeIn(400);// use hide then fadein
    add_left_right_arrows_to_zoombox();

    // also set the background to be clickable for exit.
    $("#exitdiv").hide().fadeIn(400); // use hide then fadein
}
```